# How to use .finally() without .then()?

Tags: angularjs, q

I want a block of code to run after every resolution/rejection of a promise (using `$q` in AngularJS 1.6.x).

I know I can do:

```
myPromise()
  .then((response) => {
     // Do my important stuff here
  })
  .catch((response) => {
     // Copy code from above
  })
```

As well as this (slightly better):

```
myPromise()
  .catch(() => {})
  .then((response) => {
    // Do my important stuff here, and only write it once
  })
```

But I just want to write something like:

```
myPromise()
  .finally((response) => {
    // Do my important stuff here, only written once
  })
```

But it seems `.finally()` will not run without a then() or catch() block handling the resolution/rejection first.

Any way to do this?

Comment: this doesn't exactly make sense.  Are you essentially saying you don't care if the response is a success or failure and just want to do the same thing in both cases?  what happens when the failure creates a situation that causes your code to be not runnable?  It seems like you are misunderstanding how `.then` and `.catch` work here.

Comment: I suppose it's an unusual case. I'm running a polling service that will poll a given API endpoint every x milliseconds while the back-end server is processing data until it either receives a "succeeding" report, a "failing" report, or doesn't receive any report at all after y attempts. Whether the succeeding or failing report returns, the response has data that I need to process in essentially the same way. So yes in this case I need to process the data nearly the same way regardless of whether the polling service returns with `resolve` or `reject`.

Comment: The `.finally()` method does not expose a response and it does not create a new promise from what is returned. It does in fact work without a preceding `.then` or `.catch` method. Please explain your allegation that is "does not work".

Comment: @Claies I think you're on to something come to think about it. I'm going to slightly rewrite the polling service definition function (which determines success vs failure) rather than treat bad data as a failure. Even unusable data is a successful response from the standpoint of the flow of the code. That way I can use `.then()` and `.catch()` in the standard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can do this, but the question is *why?* rather than *how?***

`.finally()` in fact *will* run even if there is no `.then()` or `.catch()` preceding it. But it's an antipattern to do so because you're avoiding handling errors that could prevent your code from running.

Additionally, since `.finally()` does not expose a response or provide a new promise, it is inferior to the other two in utility. The truth is that `.finally()` only serves the limited cases it's meant for -- to run code that should execute regardless of the fate of the promise, such as cleaning up variables that are set to indicate to the rest of the application that the promise hasn't yet returned, for instance.

So it's not a completely meaningless question, but it's not a realistic scenario to be concerned about -- where you would want to run `.finally()` without a `.then()` or `.catch()`.